# How do I pass properties to other components in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been working with some boiler-plate code for a site and was interested in making some alterations to it. Basically, what I'm trying to do is combine a "submit" data button with an "add to cart" button. From what I'm understanding, the submit button is sending the data to the database, and the add to cart button is adding that data to the cart.

I have two files. The first is below. This is what I'm assuming is the component for housing the information for "onSubmit".

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Typography, Button, Form, Input } from 'antd';
import axios from 'axios';
import FileUpload from '../../utils/FileUpload';

const { Title } = Typography;
const { TextArea } = Input; 

export class UploadProductPage extends Component {

    state = {
        title: '',
        description: '',
        continents: 1,
        images: [],
        price: 0
    }

    handleChangeTitle = (event) => {
        this.setState({ title: event.currentTarget.value })
    }

    handleChangePrice = (event) => {
        this.setState({ price: parseInt(event.currentTarget.value, 10) })
    }

    handleChangeDecsription = (event) => {
        // console.log(event.currentTarget.value)
        this.setState({ description: event.currentTarget.value })
    }

    onSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        if (this.props.user.userData && !this.props.user.userData.isAuth) {
            return alert('Please Log in First')
        }

        if (!this.state.title || !this.state.description || !this.state.images
            || !this.state.price) {
            return alert('Please first fill all the fields')
        }

        const variables = {
            writer: this.props.user.userData._id,
            title: this.state.title,
            description: this.state.description,
            images: this.state.images,
            continents: this.state.continents,
            price: this.state.price
        }

        axios.post('/api/product/uploadProduct', variables)
            .then(response => {
                if (response.data.success) {
                    alert('video Uploaded Successfully')
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        this.props.history.push('/')
                    }, 1000);
                } else {
                    alert('Failed to upload video')
                }
            })
    }

    updateFiles = (newImages) => {
        this.setState({ images: newImages })
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div style={{ maxWidth: '700px', margin: '2rem auto' }}>
            <div style={{ textAlign: 'center', marginBottom: '2rem' }}>
                <Title level={2} > Upload Travel Product</Title>
            </div>

            <Form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>

               <FileUpload refreshFunction={this.updateFiles} />

                <br /><br />
                <label>Title</label>
                <Input
                    onChange={this.handleChangeTitle}
                    value={this.state.title}
                />
                <br /><br />
                <label>Description</label>
                <TextArea
                    onChange={this.handleChangeDecsription}
                    value={this.state.description}
                />
                <br /><br />
                <label>Price($)</label>
                <Input
                    type="number"
                    onChange={this.handleChangePrice}
                    value={this.state.price}
                />
                <br /><br />

                <br /><br />

                <Button type="primary" size="large" onClick={this.onSubmit}>
                    Submit
                </Button>
            </Form>
        </div>
        )
    }
}

export default UploadProductPage
```

The second file is this, and is what I'm assuming is working on adding the products to cart:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, Component } from 'react'
import { Button, Descriptions } from 'antd';
import UploadProductPage from '../../UploadProductPage/ProductFormComponents';
import axios from 'axios';

function ProductInfo(props) {


    const [Product, setProduct] = useState({})

    useEffect(() => {

        setProduct(props.detail)

    }, [props.detail])

    const addToCarthandler = () => {
        props.addToCart(props.detail._id)
    }



    return (
        <div style={{position: 'center'}}>


            <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                <Button size="large" shape="round" type="danger" 
                    onClick={() => {
                        addToCarthandler();
                    }}
                >
                    Add to Cart
                    </Button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ProductInfo
```

What i've been trying to do is pass the props for "onSubmit" to the second file, so I can add it above the "addToCarthandler" function in the return. I am unsure if this is possible or the right way to approach the matter, but it's what I've been working on to no avail. Thanks for yout time.

Comment: Whats the relation between `ProductInfo` and `UploadProductPage` component?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "relation". In the original boiler-plate code, the UploadProductPage saves input to database. It is then gotten by ProductInfo and inserted into a "cart".

Comment: I meant do components share the same parent or one of them is the parent? Hierarchy would be a better word than relation. My apologies. As for passing props you can add to existing jsx in code <UploadProductPage onSubmit={onSubmit}/> prop so you could use `props.onSubmit`. That's why I wanted to know the thing above. If that's not the case and components are in different place I think you should extract `onSubmit` logic to separate file and share it with es module syntax